# Why does my factorial program return 0 in C?

Tags: c

so I am writing my first program in C and I'm trying to write a factorial function but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 5;
int counter;

int factorial (int x)
{
  int counter = 1;

  for ( x > 0; x<= 100;)
    counter = counter * x;

  x = x - 1;
}

int main (int factorial)
{
  printf ("%i", counter);
}
```

So yeah don't exactly know why this doesn't work? Any help :)

Comment: Well it starts already here: `for ( x > 0; x<= 100;)` <- See the error? Okay, little [hint](http://www.w3resource.com/c-programming/images/c-for-statement.jpg)

Comment: Get some good tutorial on C `for` loop, factorial, function return

Comment: You aren't calling your factorial function.  All your program does is print out the value of `counter`, which is initialized to zero because it is a global.  Also, command line parameters to your program are not passed to `main` that way.

Comment: because your code has many mistakes.

Comment: Okay so the return function returns the value at the end of the for loop right. And then when I run the main function the new value of counter has that value.

Comment: @Rizier123 And I don't exactly know the error there?

Comment: I think perhaps the factorial function is a little too far ahead for your level of understanding of C right now. I would recommend you [start to learn C from the beginning](http://www.learncpp.com/), get comfortable with the idea of loops, function calls, and variable scope, and *then* come back to this project once you have the basics down.

Comment: What are you even trying to do by writing a code like that...?

Comment: @RohitSaluja It's for a class we have to learn C syntax for spring break and prove sterlings approximation to 0.1% and plot it with gnuplot. The class started off in bash and now it's moving into C so I am a little lost since this is definitely not my field of work.

Comment: I meant there are lot of problem with the code, Just grab a cup of coffee/beer whatever u like , sit down with a good C book and start off with the very basics, You need to clear your concepts and make that foundation strong

Answer (score 1):

updated answer

```
//int x = 5; this isn't doing anything
//int counter; not doing anything

int factorial(int x)
{
    int counter = 1;
    /*
    for (x > 0; x <= 100;)
        counter = counter * x;
    1) x is input, don't use as counter, not in this case anyway
    2) The variable 'counter' is where x is supposed to be
    3) the loop is infinite
    */

    x = 1; //initialize x
    for (counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++)
        x = x * counter;

    //x = x - 1; shouldn't be here

    //x has to be returned
    return x;
}

//int main(int factorial) //don't put random arguments in main
int main() 
{
    //call the function
    printf("%i", factorial( 5 ));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sure OP can get hundreds of factorial code all over web, simply dumping code doesn't help anyone, specially for simple posts

Comment: @P0W I've written the code in bash but I am having trouble with moving it over to C. I think the syntax and different things like return is really new...took me like 40 minutes to figure out the "%i" for printf

Comment: Okay P0W, that's a good point. There is like 1000 other examples easily searchable. I was trying to remember what factorial is, I thought I write it down while I am at.

Comment: @SulimanSharif learn from a book. C is not suited to trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not calling the function  so initial value of counter which is a garbage value would be printed out.